# Remove Words By Suffix

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a simple JavaScript function to remove all occurrences of a word with particular suffix in a string.

```
function removeClassBySuffix(s, suffix) {
    var regx = new RegExp(what-regex-to-put-here, 'g');
    s = s.replace(regx, '');
    return s;
}

/* new RegExp('\\b.+?' + suffix + '\\b', 'g') -- doesn't work */
```

So,

```
removeClassBySuffix('hello title-edit-panel deal-edit-panel there', '-edit-panel');
// Should return 'hello   there'.
```

Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried it but I think the following should work:

`new RegExp('\\b\\S+?' + suffix + '\\b', 'g')`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
function removeClassBySuffix(s, suffix) {
    var a = s.split( ' ' ),
    result = [];

    for (i in a)
        if ( a[i].indexOf( suffix ) != ( a[i].length - suffix.length ) )
            result.push( a[i] );

    return result.join(' ');
}
```